# Function to zip a CSV file in python

Tags: function, csv, path, zip

I am trying to make a function which uses as arguments the source path, source file, target path, target file and that way convert an CSV file into zip. I am new to both python and this site so if you can please help me.

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far and explain exactly where you are stuck. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

def create_zip(source_path, source_file, target_path, target_file):
    # get full path of source and target
    source_filepath = os.path.join(source_path, source_file)
    target_filepath = os.path.join(target_path, target_file)
    # make a new empty zip file at target
    with ZipFile(target_filepath, 'w') as new_zipfile:
        # write source into it
        new_zipfile.write(source_filepath)
```